# Change div background-image randomly on page refresh using Angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

As I'm new to using AngularJS, I would like to know how can I change a `div` `background-image` randomly on page refresh.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach should be:-
1.) Declare an array inn your controller which contains name of the image files.
2.) Assign the length of the array to a variable.
3.) Generate a random no between 0 to length of array-1, since most of the time we assume that array start with index 0.
4.) Then just store that random no in a variable and use it in your HTML page.

so index.html:-

```
<html ng-app='myapp'>
<body ng-controller='myctrl'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:url('img/{{item[rand]}}.png'); padding: 100px;">{{item[rand]}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

your app.js:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
    app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.item = ['dairy','discount','cleaning-spray']; //Declare a array which contains various colors
        $scope.val=$scope.item.length; //assign the length of array to a variable
        $scope.rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.val); // generate a random no . and make use of it as index of array
        //console.log($scope.rand);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful Link about change background image on refresh page in **Angular 11.**

[change background image on refresh page](https://github.com/mabdullah786/Change-background-Image-on-refresh-in-Angular)